# Gmail Api to access the delegated emails

Tags: gmail, gmail-api

I can able to access email using gmailapi in c# code but i cant able to access the delegated emails. Is there any gmail Api available to access the delegated inbox emails using C# code ?

using Oauth credential i am accessing this credential.

To give more clarity to my question ,

In my case delegation is not happening on one account to another account level.

My Site IT admin have created a Mail box(This is not an account but a shared mail box ) and have delegated /shared this with 25 users(Max users)

My requirement is to find a way to access the Delegated Mail box Emails.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get mails of delegated accounts](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13359672/how-to-get-mails-of-delegated-accounts)

Comment: The above post is not relevant to my post

Comment: If that is true then please read http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and improve your question so that it does not appear to be relevant.   It appears to be the same question.

Comment: To give more clarity to my question ,

I my case delegation is not happening on one account to another account level.

My Site IT admin have created a MAil box(This is not an account but a shared mail box ) and have delegated /shared this with 25 users(Max users) 

My requirement is to find a way to access the Delegated MAil box Emails.

Answer (score 2):

You would need to authenticate as the delegated user with Gmail API, not your own account. There's no way to pull delegated inbox data through the Gmail API. The extent of the API's capabilities involve what you can do in your own inbox alone.

Comment: Thanks for this answer. I was also trying to retrieve emails from a delegate account and was not able to. I think the extent of the API only allows you to check what is the status of a delegate account in terms of delegation, but not retrieve any of its information.

https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/guides/delegate_settings

Answer (score -2):

Based from the Google Apps Admin SDK documetation, [Email Settings API](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/email-settings) which enables Google partners to programmatically manipulate most user-level Google Mail settings has already been depracated.

You may want to try [EWS Managed API](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dd633710(v=exchg.80).aspx) and see if it works for you. I've read about this [blog](http://www.rahulsingla.com/blog/2010/12/exchange-saving-mails-to-delegated-user's-mailbox-with-ews-managed-api) which discussed that, with the use of EWS Managed API, if you (the delegate) are accessing someone else's (the delegator's) mailbox via Exchange delegation, any mails sent on behalf of the delegator would appear in your (delegate's) mailbox's Sent Items. Ideally, it should have shown in the delegator's sent items.

For a more detailed information, please visit [EWS Managed API 2.0 documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dd633710(v=exchg.80).aspx).

Comment: How would the EWS Managed API help him access mail on Google? Is Google planning to start using EWS Managed API?